# What does an Unseen Servant roll for skill checks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, skills

Let's say that Lazarus the Lazy is an eighth level wizard. He is too lazy to wash his dishes, so he simply uses them once and throws them out every day. Each night before bed, he summons an Unseen Servant. "Make me a spoon!" he commands. (Wisdom was his dump stat.)

The Unseen Servant "can't perform any task that requires a skill check with a DC higher than 10 or that requires a check using a skill that can't be used untrained." But Craft is usable untrained, and "wooden spoon" is listed as an example of a DC 5 check, so this should be within its capabilities.

What should the roll be? Can the servant take 10?

For bonus credit, can this answer be extended to other skills the servant can use?

Comment: By *What should the roll be?* do you mean what are the ability scores of the effect created by the *unseen servant* or something else? (I don't want to write *A d20*, for instance.) Also, in your research have you found something that indicated the effect could *not* take 10 on a skill check? (That is, is this weirder than, like, a dog taking 10 on a skill check?)

Comment: Since the Servant is an effect, and not a creature, I'd say it is a little more unusual than a dog taking ten. The crux of the problem is what it means to have no stats, I suppose.

Comment: For reasons I don't pretend to understand, *Pathfinder* eliminates the *3.5* concept of [nonabilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#nonabilities), the presence of which would've made this question far easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I can't find anything that either prohibits the US from taking 10, or that indicates it has any bonuses on skill rolls. The only exception is it's "effective Strength score of 2", so it would have -4 on rolls for Strength skills (which really shouldn't affect anything given its other limitations).

So, the roll for all skills would be 1d20+0, except for Strength skills which are 1d20-4.

And yes, the US can take 10 (with the usual requirements of that).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for Lazarus the Lazy, he's either going to need to make those spoons himself or go out and buy them. While useful for carrying things around, his beloved friend the Unseen Servant is, unfortunately, mindless.

> **Mindless**: No Intelligence score, and immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, phantasms, patterns, and morale effects).

With no Intelligence score, it can be safely argued that Lazarus's Servant is incapable of using the Craft (Spoons) skill, since it is Int based.

Comment: A mindless creature can still follow orders, though. (Yet it might be up to the GM to regulate the complexity of those orders.)

Comment: But even a mindless creature must have some kind of baseline to follow *any* orders. You can verbally order a mindless thing to pick up something and not have to first demonstrate what *pick up* means and without first pointing at the something, right?

Comment: Huh. So an *unseen servant* can be commanded successfully to *mend* a broken wooden spoon (that is, commanded to use its abysmal Craft skill to repair an object), but it can't be commanded to *make* a wooden spoon (that is, commanded to use its abysmal Craft skill for something not directly mentioned in the spell)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39535/discussion-between-weaveworker89-and-hey-i-can-chan).